# Using root_scalar to calculate unknown variable with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

Im trying to calculate an unknown variable in my function using SciPy's root_scalar. I define all my known variables, leaving me one unknown variable which is the one im interested in calculating. The code goes as follows:

```
Llv = -2.5008*(10**6)
Cpd = 1004 
Cpv = 1860
Rd = 287.05
pi= 1000
pf = 150
Ti= 300
rv= 15*(10**-3)
ri = 0
rl = 0
Rm = Rd + (rv * 461.5)
Cl = 4218

def EQ_152(pi,pf, Ti, Tf, rv, rl, ri, Cpd, Rd, Llv, Cl):

    p_d_i = pi*((1 + (rv/1.61))**-1)
    p_d_f = pf*((1 + (rv/1.61))**-1)

    term1 = Cpd * (np.log(Tf)-np.log(Ti))
    term2 = Rd*np.log(p_d_f/p_d_i)
    term3 = ((rv*Llv)/(Tf-Ti/Ti))
    term7 = (rv + rl + ri) * Cl * (Tf - Ti / Ti) 
    function = term1 - term2 + term3 + term7

    return function

sol = root_scalar(EQ_152, args=(pi,pf, Ti, rv, rl, ri, Cpd, Rd, Llv, Cl))
print(sol)
```

But Im getting an error that is unable to select a solver as neither bracket nor starting point is provided. Is my first time using this type of function, so I dont seem to figure out how the bracket or the starting point are affecting my results even though in the documentation for SciPy says that are optional. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking at this issue, I want to clarify that on the line:

```
sol = root_scalar(EQ_152, args=(pi,pf, Ti, rv, rl, ri, Cpd, Rd, Llv, Cl))
```

I forgot to include x0 in this case representing my initial temperature which made the program iterate invite times through the equation without finding a real answer. So I modified it to:

```
sol = root_scalar(EQ_152, args=(pi,pf, Ti, rv, rl, ri, Cpd, Rd, Llv, Cl), x0=Ti)
```

and it fixed the issue.